# Local host interrupts data read with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've saved a JSON file in my local direcotry. The current path is "application/data/file.json". I'm using getJSON to read this file but I keep getting an error saying "jquery-3.6.0.js:10109          GET http://127.0.0.1/data/history.json 404 (NOT FOUND)".

I'm trying to get the data from the json file as a part of building web application. In the html script, I set something like this and I wonder if the host url is interrupting the data read with JSON.

```
{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var host_api_url = "{{host_url}}"
</script>
<script src="static/script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using json getJSON to read the data from the json file and create some html components in my js script like this:

```
$.getJSON("application/data/file.json", function(data) {      
    $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
        $("<div />", { "class":"group" })
        .append($("<p />", {name:"title"+i, id:"title"+i, text: key }))
        .appendTo(".output");
        $("<div />", { "class":"group" })
        .append($("<p />", {id:"content"+i, text: value }))
        .appendTo(".output");
        i++;
    })   
});
```

Is there any way to get the data from the local directory and resolve the error I specified above?

Comment: The `host_api_url` is quite confusing - what does it do? I don't see it being used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you need to serve that `file.json` through a web server, in your case running on `127.0.0.1` since `jQuery.getJSON()` is using a HTTP GET request - it will not read a local file directly.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success

The error message indicates that you likely misplaced the file in the wrong directory.

Note that you cannot read arbitrary local files from a browser environment programmatically (due to the browser sandbox principle).
**If this JSON file is an end-user supplied file**, you can ask the user to

1. drag and drop it into the browser and then use the FileReader API to read that file, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API or
2. ask the user to select a local file through an  `<INPUT>` form element.

Starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Once you have the file read in, use `data = JSON.parse(textcontent)` to parse it as JSON and retrieve the JS object `data`.